# Read uncommitted when using Rob Conery's Massive

Tags: isolation-level, massive, nolock, read-uncommitted

Is there a way to do a read uncommitted when using Rob Conery's Massive without writing your own query?

It is for a site that is mostly read-only. A CMS type of a site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheat way to do this is when you are doing your declaration for the table. Pass in a (nolock) hint:

```
var dirtytbl = new DynamicModel("northwind", tableName:"dbo.Products (nolock)", primaryKeyField:"ProductID");
```

If you don't want to have established dirty models and clean models, for the what I hope to be rare times you are doing this, you can just go straight to SQL:

```
var dirtyresult = tbl.Fetch("set transaction isolation level read uncommitted; SELECT * FROM Categories c INNER JOIN things t on c.id = t.id ");
```

I use the above code for system objects and some other behind the scenes stuff where I know it won't matter, but you should always be very cautious and know what you are getting into when you drop to that isolation level.
See blog post *[How dirty are your reads?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2009/04/10/how-dirty-are-your-reads.aspx)*

Comment: it is a site that is mostly read only. A cms type of a site. thanks